# get 'ldftn' function pointer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr, function-pointers, cil

in cil code, ldftn is used to get the function pointer address to call the delegate constructor(i.e. .ctor(object, native int)).
How to get the function pointer used to construct delegate in C#?

Comment: Do you want the raw pointer address, or do you just want a delegate object in a variable?

Comment: the function pointer used to call the .ctor (i.e. .ctor(object, [native int]))

Comment: It's pretty unclear what ctor you are talking about.  The _methodPtr value can only be generated by the JIT compiler.  There's nothing to call until it generates the machine code for the method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is phrased in a way that makes it hard to understand what you're actually trying to do.  I think that perhaps what you want is something like this:

```
MethodInfo mi = ...
var ptr = mi.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
// now call a delegate .ctor using that ptr
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for how the Reflection.Emit code should look, then something like this:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, yourMethodInfo);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, yourDelegateType.GetConstructors()[0]);
```

The first line loads the function pointer onto the stack.  The second line "passes" it to the constructor of the delegate.  `yourDelegateType` should be something like `typeof(Func<string>)`, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's a way to create delegate in Reflection.Emit. But i only want the function pointer i.e. the output of ldftn

Comment: @Kii, what do you want to do with it?  Can you provide some (pseudo) code that illustrates what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: once upon a time, there is a method:
object create_object(object[] args)  
            
then i want to create a delegate through the method :  
            
object _delegate = create_object(new object[] { null , get_ptr(method_info) });

Comment: @Kii, but why is it not sufficient for create_object to return the delegate?  That's the only thing that can be passed around natively in C# wrt to function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

ldftn available in C# 9 .NET 5
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/dotnet-five

`Function pointers: Language constructs that expose the following intermediate language (IL) opcodes: ldftn and calli.`